# SCSS linear gradient effect

Tags: colors, sass, linear-gradients

I have many `spans` that are one next to each other and I'd like to add some *linear-gradient effect* - so the first one has `background-color: $a`, the last one `background-color: $b` and the `spans` between the *"transition color from $a to $b"*. If I'm not making any sense, this image will help you:

[image]

I tried with [lighten()](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method), but it only uses one color.

[image]

Here's the current SCSS:

```
$starting_color:  #177DEF;
$ending_color:    #2FF0D5;

$elements: 51;
@for $i from 0 to $elements {
    span:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        height: random(260) + px;
        background-color: lighten($starting_color, $i);
    }
}
```

[Whole fiddle on Codepen](http://codepen.io/vucko/pen/XKmJzb)

How can I create this *"effect"*? Possible with some `step` parameter (step count = all spans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite lengthy, but it works:

```
//$blue: #177DEF;
$firstR: 23;
$firstG: 239;
$firstB: 125;
$blue: rgb(23, 125, 239);
//$green: #2FF0D5;
$secondR: 47;
$secondG: 240;
$secondB: 213;
$green: rgb(47, 240, 213);

body{
    background-color: #000;
}

#panel {
    font-size: 0;
}

span {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 10px;
    &:not(:first-of-type) {
        margin-left: 2px;
    }
}

$elements: 51;
$redDiv: ($firstR - $secondR) / $elements;
@if $redDiv < 0 {
    $redDiv: $redDiv * -1
}
$greenDiv: ($firstG - $secondG) / $elements;
@if $greenDiv < 0 {
    $greenDiv: $greenDiv * -1
}
$blueDiv: ($firstB - $secondB) / $elements;
@if $blueDiv < 0 {
    $blueDiv: $blueDiv * -1
}
@for $i from 0 to $elements {
    $redValue: $redDiv * $i;
    $greenValue: $greenDiv * $i;
    $blueValue: $blueDiv * $i;
    span:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        height: random(260) + px;
        background-color: rgb($firstR + $redValue, $firstG + $greenValue, $firstB + $blueValue);
    }
}
```

I converted the hexadecimal values to RGB [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm), then made separate variables for each red, green, blue value in both colors.

Subtract the second value from the first then divide by how many elements (this gives you the amount of change needed each iteration).

Make sure the values aren't negative with `@if`.

Calculate the change by multiplying by `$i` and then add/subtract that change depending upon which value was lesser (first or second). If first value is less then `$first + $value`, if second value is less then `$first - $value`.

**This was the only part that needs to be changed depending on the colors, the rest will work for any RGB value.**

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezpmXJ

Comment: Nice one, but it seems that the "transition" isn't completed? The starting "green" is good, but it doesn't end in the ending "blue"?

Comment: Look at the codepen again, I have created blocks that show the begin and end colors. They look identical;

Comment: Yea, it sure is. My bad, I was looking wrong. Thanks for the solution. Cheers